# CodeIgniter - Store _post data in multidimensional array and displaying

Tags: codeigniter, post, multidimensional-array

I have a form on my page. On "submit" I need to get the post data from the form and store it in a multidimensional array.

This is what I have so far.

```
//view
<input type="text" name="option[fname]" />
<input type="text" name="option[lname]" />
<input type="submit" />

//controller
$data['myarray'] = $this->input->post('options', TRUE);
$this->load->view('template',$data);
```

Then on "submit" we go back to the view and see what we have added.

```
//view
<?php
foreach($myarray as $row){
    echo $myarray['fname'] . '<br>' . $myarray['lname'];
}
?>
```

I want to be able to keep adding to the array each time I hit "submit". Right now it is only displaying the last entered data. How do I do that? Thanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must save your array in a file, a cookie or a database at each request.

Simplified example with saving to file:

```
// controller
// load array from the file if exists
if (is_file('myarray.dat')) $myarray = unserialize(file_get_contents('myarray.dat'));
// put new data to array
$myarray[] = $this->input->post('options', TRUE);
// output array
$this->load->view('template', array('myarray' => $myarray));
// save array back to the file
file_put_contents('myarray.dat', serialize($myarray));
```